# How can I edit a regular expression search string as if it were a file?

Tags: command-line, regular-expression

Sometimes a regular expression starts to get pretty complex, and it's hard to edit in Vim's commandline.

It seems the obvious way is to edit the search term as though it's a file and be able to switch between editing it and testing it as an actual search.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You can paste into the command line with `<Ctrl-R>`  followed by the name of the register you want to paste from (e.g. `*` for the Windows clipboard.)

Comment: Actually I can paste into the commandline with Ctrl-V but copying from it is harder. Specifically it's hard to copy or paste just part of it.

Comment: Ah okay. `<Ctrl-R>` is still good to know about, though, because a). it works everywhere (`Ctrl-V` does something completely different for me), and b). it works for other registers too.

Comment: Yes I know they made compromises with copypaste on Windows so it could use its normal keystrokes and the functions which were tied to those keystrokes on other OSes got moved in Windows. That's why I originally included the windows tag in my question ...

Comment: @hippietrail How to copy/paste from the command line in Windows, and how to *"edit a regular expression search string as if it were a file"* are really 2 different questions ;-) It's a good topic for a *second* question.

Comment: Well yes. The abstract problem is "I want to copy and past subexpressions in regexes in the vim commandline" and one specific approach is "if I knew a way to edit the regex as if it were a file I could solve my abstract problem".

Comment: @hippietrail It feels more to me (and I presume @Carpetsmoker) that the abstract problem is "I want to be able to edit regular expressions more powerfully" and two *different* specific approaches to this are 1. Copy/paste in the commandline 2. Edit the regex as if it's a file.

Comment: Well that's a generalization of my problem I suppose (-: The specific power was long subparts of search strings used more than one, but the full power of an edit buffer seemed like something I thought must be in Vim though my Googling failed probably because I didn't know the key jargon... Ah I see the specific part about reusing subexpressions was edited out...

Comment: Both the title and the question itself ask *"How can I edit a regular expression search string as if it were a file?"* ;-) The Windows copy/paste thing just seemed like an off-hand remark to me. You can always revert my edit, or make more edits to your question ;-)

Comment: I'll leave it. On some SE sites they just want your core question. On others they want you to provide backstory to show how it's really a problem you're facing.

Answer (score 6):

Use `<C-f>` from the command-line or `q/` from normal mode to open the command-line window.

Note that `q/` specifically opens your command-line history in the command-line window but `<C-f>` is contextually aware: it will open the right history for the current command-line and is thus the exact answer to your question.

See this documentation from [`:help cmdline-window`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdwin):

> There are two ways to open the command-line window:
>
> 1. From Command-line mode, use the key specified with the `'cedit'` option.    The default is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> when `'compatible'` is not set.
> 2. From Normal mode, use the `q:`, `q/` or `q?` command.    This starts editing an Ex command-line (`q:`) or search string (`q/` or
>    `q?`).  Note that this is not possible while recording is in progress
>    (the    `q` stops recording then).

Comment: I guess I don't know my Vim jargon. Is something called the "command-line window" that is not the single line at the bottom of Vim where I type commands? \-:

Comment: For searches started with `/`, you'd want to use `q/` instead of `q:`

Comment: @hippietrail No, that's the command line. As @romainl suggests, you should read `:help cmdline-window`. (Or just try it out!)

Comment: Oh so you're saying that rather than edit the regex as though it were a file I should edit the whole commandline as though it were a file?

Comment: If you type `q/` instead of `/` vim will open a new window with your search history that you can edit as if it were a file.

Comment: @MattBoehm: Aha! This part about `q/` should be in the answer then.

Comment: The answer would be better too if it somehow introduced the concept and/or jargon "command-line" window" since I suppose others will be like me in that though they've used Vim for years never had to use this feature before.